# Export Folder Permissions

Tags: powershell

I want to Export folder Permissions for a subset of folders. 
Each Folder in `Department` has two child's, `Public` and `Internal`.

For example, I want the permissions of the folder `D:\Data\Department\Science\Public` or `D:\Data\Department\Sales\Public`.

```
$FolderPath = dir -Directory -Path "D:\Data\Department" -Force
$Report = @()
Foreach ($Folder in $FolderPath) 
{
$Folder2 = Join-Path -Path $Folder -ChildPath "Public"

$Acl = Get-Acl $Folder2.FullName

foreach ($Access in $acl.Access)
{
$Properties = [ordered]@{'FolderName'=$Folder2.FullName;'AD
Group or User'=$Access.IdentityReference;'Permissions'=$Access.FileSystemRights;'Inherited'=$Access.IsInherited}
$Report += New-Object -TypeName PSObject -Property $Properties
}
}
$Report | Export-Csv -path "C:\Users\adminrw\FolderPermissions.csv"
```

**Error**:

```
Get-Acl : Cannot validate argument on parameter 'Path'. The argument is null or empty. Provide an argument that is not null or empty, and then try the command again.
At line:7 char:16
+ $Acl = Get-Acl $Folder2.FullName
+                ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidData: (:) [Get-Acl], ParameterBindingValidationException
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the Join-Path in your script is taking the Name of the folder and adding the childpath to it.  This results in `$Folder2` ending up like `SomeFolder\Public`

Try using

```
$Folder2 = Join-Path -Path $Folder.FullName -ChildPath "Public"
```

This will make `$Folder2` : `D:\Data\Department\SomeFolder\Public`

Comment: You also need to remove '.Fullname' from `$Acl = Get-Acl $Folder2.FullName` as `$Folder2` is just a string and not a directory object.

Answer (score 0):

I've corrected script. Please use below code:

```
$FolderPath = dir -Directory -Path "D:\Data\Department" -Force | Select *
$Report = @()
Foreach ($Folder in $FolderPath) 
{
$Folder2 = Join-Path -Path $Folder.FullName -ChildPath "Public"

$Acl = Get-Acl $Folder2

foreach ($Access in $acl.Access)
{
$Properties = [ordered]@{'FolderName'=$Folder2.FullName;'AD
Group or User'=$Access.IdentityReference;'Permissions'=$Access.FileSystemRights;'Inherited'=$Access.IsInherited}
$Report += New-Object -TypeName PSObject -Property $Properties
}
}
$Report | Export-Csv -path "C:\Users\adminrw\FolderPermissions.csv"
```